# Twitter Web Intent Icons / Sprite Sheet

Tags: twitter, icons

According to Twitter, I can find the twitter icons for reblog, retweet, and favorite on their [Twitter Brand Resources](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/image-resources) page.

I was able to right click and save the images of the icons at the bottom, but they are not in the best quality.

Maybe I'm missing a link or something, but where can I find the Twitter Web Intent icons?  Does Twitter provide these?  I don't think I'm allowed to use non-twitter icons for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter Web Intents have updated and they now provide SVGs for the three icons!

These icons can be found on their [Brand Resources](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/image-resources) page.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure how this falls into Twitter's EULA, but

Twitter uses a font they call "Rosetta Icon Font" (I suppose it was made by http://icondesign.rosetta.com/?)

A font [of? based on?] the Rosetta icons (unauthorized?) is available at https://github.com/biwek/twitter-fe/tree/master/public/fonts

An example of what the CSS will look like is https://github.com/biwek/twitter-fe/blob/master/public/css/styles.css, currently lines 9-40